# Where can I find the ints that represent screen orientation

Tags: android

I need to lock the screen orientation for a short period of time to which ever orientation the user is currently on. I know that to get the current orientation you do:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

int orientation = display.getOrientation();
```

but then I need to be able to compare it to the integers that represent the different orientations like so:

```
if (orientation == MysteryAndroidClass.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{ 
    //lock orientation in portrait
}

else
{
    //lock orientation in landscape
}
```

The problem is that I can't find these constants anywhere in the docs. Perhaps someone knows how to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  `MysteryAndroidClass`  is  `android.content.res.Configuration`

`int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

int ORIENTATION_SQUARE

int ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html